# Fail to send data to database using Volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, post, android-volley

My application receive region name from **`mapActivity`** by using **`getStringExtra`**, then included with the string obtained from current activity which is **`General_Info`**, need to be sent to online database.

There is no error in PHP code.

I have tested app using wi-fi and data but unfortunately, it always return "fail".

I have no idea what is the problem with my code.

Attached are my code

```
StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains("SUCCESS")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "system error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> param=new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("householdid",houseNo.getText().toString());
            param.put("region", region);
            param.put("totalmembers", totalMembers.getText().toString());
            param.put("totalfemale", totalFemale.getText().toString());
            param.put("totalmale", totalMale.getText().toString());

            return param;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(General_Info.this).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

php code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    include_once("connect.php");

    $householdId = $_POST['householdid'];
    $region = $_POST['region'];
    $totalMembers = $_POST['totalmembers'];
    $totalFemale = $_POST['totalfemale'];
    $totalMale = $_POST['totalmale'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO households (householdId,region,totalMembers,totalFemale,totalMale) 
      VALUES ('$householdId',' $region','$totalMembers','$totalFemale',' $totalMale')");

    if($result == true) {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    else{
        echo "FAILURE ";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I think you missed the code :)

Comment: Put logs in all of the responses you receive (Log.d) and paste the response you are getting. Also, use the code button when you paste your code, don't do it as you did, with attaching a picture.

Comment: use Log for every param u put and also log the response..

Comment: First of all, I suggest you to use Retrofit...it's so much easier than Volley.
And like others said, put some logs using `Log.d` and watch your log cat

Comment: post your url plz, without this how i will test what problem you are facing

Comment: `it always return "fail".` No. That is not what 'it' returns. You are toasting that yourself instead. You should also toast 'response' there as you might want to know if the php script returned "FAILED" or "SUCCESS". Please report.

Comment: The php script does not always echo. You should add an echo for that case too.

Comment: Thank you for feedback,i have tried retrofit as suggested by @Mohammad Z,and still it gives same problem.I am testing my app in Galaxy note II using reliable mobile data.Let me make it clear ,As far as I am testing most of the time it returns fail ,few times returns success response even if i use asynctask,volley or retrofit.What could be the problem?I have log the response too                             D/com.hairunidev.censustz.app.General_Info: failure

Comment: i mean 'D/com.hairunidev.censustz.app.General_Info: failure' is shown in my logcat

Comment: @Dinesh,here is url (http://hairunidev.com/android/houseHold_generalInfo.php)

Comment: @Heyrooney check your api responce on POSTMAN or AdwanceRestClient , always giving "failure" response, so you cant check it as a SUCCESS responce key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I make change to code like this. First of all, I use [medoo](http://medoo.in/) as my database framework which is really easy to use and it's fully documented.
If you use it, your insert will be like this:

```
$householdId = $_POST['householdid'];
$region = $_POST['region'];
$totalMembers = $_POST['totalmembers'];
$totalFemale = $_POST['totalfemale'];
$totalMale = $_POST['totalmale'];

// $database is an object which you declared using medoo.
$result = $database->insert("households",[
    "householdId" => $householdId,
    "region" => $region,
    "totalMembers" => $totalMembers,
    "totalFemale" => $$totalFemale,
    "totalMale" => $totalMale
    ]);
```

And as in [documentation](http://medoo.in/api/insert) said for insert:

> Return: [number] The last insert id

So you just check it `$result` is >= 1 or not:

```
if($result >= 1) {
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else{
    echo "FAILURE ";
}
```

I think it will work as your server. And for your client it will be something like this:

First you need a service generator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://your.api-base.url";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Then you must write your own interface...lets say we have your web service is something like this: `http://your.api-base.url/my-service/insert.php`

And your interface:

```
public interface MyClient {  
    @POST("/myservice/insert.php")
    Call<String> insert(
        @Body("householdid") String householdId,
        @Body("region") String region,
        @Body("totalmembers") String totalMembers,
        @Body("totalfemale") String totalFemale,
        @Body("totalmale") String totalMale
    );
}
```

Well, now everything is ready.

For calling the method you should do this:

```
MyClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(MyClient.class);
Call<String> insertCall = client.insert(houseNo.getText().toString(),
        region,
        totalMembers.getText().toString(),
        totalFemale.getText().toString(),
        totalMale.getText().toString());

        insertCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    if(response != null && response.isSuccessful()){
                        // you have a response...handle it
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<OwnerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    //PROBLEM!!!
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Z:) already solved the problem ,infact i had a problem with my database structure,and all this you have posted helped me too.Thank you so much